# pagenote and memoir: \printnotes undefined

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, pagenote

If I understood it correctly, `pagenote` should work fine with the `memoir` class, yet it doesn't... If I change the `documentclass` to `article`, the example below compiles, but not with `memoir`.

I'm feeling kind of silly ... is there some typo somewhere ? Can anyone see what the problem is here ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Titre}

\author{A. Teur}

\maketitle

Texte\pagenote{Some text}.

\clearpage{}
\chapter{Notes}
\printnotes

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27     \printnotes
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not mentioned in the "Packages" section of the introduction to the `memoir` manual, `pagenote` is one of the packages which is emulated by `memoir` (you may search for `pagenote` within `memoir.cls` to check this), and so the class effectively disables any try to load `pagenote`. You could issue `\DisemulatePackage{pagenote}` and then `\usepackage{pagenote}`, but you'd still have to undefine several macros which both the class and the package would try to define, each of which would cause an error.

Therefore, I recommend not to load `pagenote` and to replace its `\printnotes` command with its `memoir` counterpart `\printpagenotes`.

Comment: Curses! Beat me by 5 seconds :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I also discovered that `memoir`'s pagenotes does exactly what I've been looking for in `endnote`, `endheads` and `pagenote` : print the page number at the beginning of the note. This is great !